# How to toggle asp TreeNode with checkbox click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I would like to know how to toggle or expand treenode when you click checkbox.
When you uncheck the checkbox it should collapse.

As per code below i have 2 nodes

- HeadNode1
- HeadNode2

If user click HeadNode1 checkbox , it should expand down to its child and grandchild element using javascript.
When he unchecks it, it should collapse back.

The below screenshot shows the expanded view when HeadNode1 is clicked.

[image]

C# Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TreeNode tNode1 = new TreeNode();
        tNode1.Text = "HeadNode1";
        tNode1.Value = "HeadNode1";

        TreeNode h1ChildNode1 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode1.Text = "Head1Child1";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode1);

        TreeNode h1GrandChild1 = new TreeNode();
        h1GrandChild1.Text = "Head1Child1Grand1";
        h1ChildNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1GrandChild1);

        TreeNode h1ChildNode2 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode2.Text = "Head1Child2";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode2);

        TreeNode h1ChildNode3 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode3.Text = "Head1Child3";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode3);
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode1);

        TreeNode tNode2 = new TreeNode();
        tNode2.Text = "HeadNode2";
        tNode2.Value = "HeadNode2";

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode2);

        ServerSideChangeSelection(TreeView1, true);
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
        {
            nodes.Add(node);
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    nodes.Add(childNode);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

TreeView

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ShowCheckBoxes="All" Showlines="true" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click" Text="Save" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or just vanilla JS? The solution may differ depending on library you're using, but basically you need to watch `change` or `click` event from parent checkbox and expand all child checkboxes linked to the parent afterwards.

Comment: Vanilla JS . Thanks